# "unknown.prolexic.com: unknown error" in Hadoop setup

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to setup Hadoop 2.6.0 in my Mac OS

I am following this article: 
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation

when i run this command

> bin/hdfs namenode -format

i get following error.

15/01/08 09:35:03 WARN net.DNS: Unable to determine local hostname -falling back to "localhost"
java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown.prolexic.com: unknown.prolexic.com: unknown error

However when i do

> ssh localhost

, i am able to login. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Set hostname using:

```
scutil --st HostName "localhost"
```

and it will fix the issue.

Reference: http://biomedicalontologies.com/2012/11/14/fixing-java-net-local-host-name-unknown-error-on-mac-os-x/